# implicit differential equation, y is a solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, implicit-differentiation

Assume that the function $y$ is defined implicitly as a function of $x$ by the given equation. Use the technique of implicit differentiation to find a differential equation for which $y$ is a solution.
$(x^2+y^2)^2=4xy^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technique of implicit differentiation is the key in such problems. So, basically, your first step is to implicit differentiate given equation, and then  solve for $\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$.

Given equation: $(x^2+y^2)^2=4xy^2$.

1st step:

$2(x^2+y^2)(2x+2yy')=4y^2+8xyy'$

2nd step:

$4x(x^2+y^2) + 4y(x^2+y^2)y'=4y^2+8xyy'$

$y'\left[ 4y(x^2+y^2)-8xy \right] = 4y^2-4x(x^2+y^2)$

$\boxed{y' = \dfrac{4y^2-4x(x^2+y^2)}{4y(x^2+y^2-2x)}}$.

Comment: thank you so much, sir. Your steps are so clear to me. I'm a freshman in liberal arts university. I'm working hard to improve my Math. I also want to major in math in the future.

Comment: You're welcome @AmyWang.

Comment: Are you aware of the quality standards for questions on this site, and that we should only answer questions conforming to them? See for example [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/10513).